# Dividir array aleatoriamente y escribirlo en tablas

Tags: javascript, array, random

Hola que tal estoy necesitando ayuda para programar este proyecto, el cual consiste en dividir una cantidad de 10 participantes en mitades iguales aleatoriamente con javascript. Mi código hasta ahora:

```
<script>arreglo[] /*se ingresan los participantes mediante un input */</script>

 

<html>
  <div id="esquema">
        <div class="cuadros">
            <h2>Equipo 1</h2>
            <table id="equipouno">
                <tbody>
                    <td>/*Aqui deberian ir 5 participantes aleatorios  */</td>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
             
        <div class="cuadros" style="float: right; margin-right: 25%;">
         <h2>Equipo 2</h2>
         <table id="equipodos">
            <tbody>
                <td>/*Aqui deberian ir los 5 restantes */</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     
     </div>
      </div>
</html>
```

Comment: No has escrito nada de JavaScript. ¿Cual es el pregunta concreta?

Comment: En una lista se muestran todos los nombres ingresados, esa lista contendria un boton que al presionarlo se ejecute una funcion que divida dichos nombres aleatoriamente por igual en dos arreglos y se mostraria uno en la primer tabla , y el otro en la segunda. No subi mas codigo para no hacerlo tan largo

Comment: @FeedeB98 ¿Cómo consigues los nombre? ¿Qué has intentado para dividirlos? ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: Los nombres los ingreso mediante un input, clickeando un boton que llama a una funcion, esta funcion va agregando lo que ingreso a un array y se muestran en una lista. Intente dividir este arreglo mediante la funcion Math.random() pero no tuve resultados

Comment: Usualmente se toma el Array original, se desordena aleatoriamente (puedes usar el algoritmo de [Fisher - Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates) para este propósito) y luego divides el Array (usando [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) por ejemplo). Saludos

Comment: Perfecto! voy a estar probando de esa manera, muchas gracias!